# How to edit permissions on Heroku application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, file-permissions, pdftk

My problem in simple terms is that I have an executable that can't be run on Heroku, because it doesn't have the right permissions.

In more details, I have a RoR application on Heroku and I want to use server `pdftk`. But after installing it I need to `chmod` the file to be able to use it. And if I run a console on Heroku dashboard, put the chmod command in and try running pdftk it works, but it works just for that temporary dyno and it doesn't work on production server.

I tried creating .profile and putting the command in and that didn't work.
I tried creating Procfile and put `release: chmod u+x /app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk` and it didn't work.
I tried all different versions of release, web, worker...
I tried creating a .sh file and putting the command in there and then running the file and it doesn't work either.

command for setting permission: `chmod u+x /app/vendor/pdftk/bin/pdftk`

If you need more info, please tell me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's back up a moment. How are you installing `pdftk` in the first place?

Comment: i installed `pdftk` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45838005/pdftk-installation-on-heroku

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the problem was.
I have a pipeline from gitlab and the permissions just needed to be set through git, so that they were correct when they came to the production enviroment.

I needed to run this code:`git update-index --add --chmod=+x pdftk`